# Extract top-level domain in PrestoDB

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, presto

I have a large dataset of URLs that I query in AWS Athena (using PrestoDB). PrestoDB has built-in functions to extract the host of the URL. I would now like to split the host further into subdomain, domain and top-level domain (TLD).

As far as my understanding goes, this cannot actually be done with regular expressions: "Since there was and remains no algorithmic method of finding the highest level at which a domain may be registered for a particular top-level domain (the policies differ with each registry), the only method is to create a list." (from https://publicsuffix.org/learn/). Packages in Python and R (see [here](https://rdrr.io/github/jayjacobs/tldextract/src/R/tldextract.R)) accordingly use the list of TLDs from publicsuffix.org. To my knowledge, nothing equivalent exists for PrestoDB. Note that the data set is to large to export and process in R or Python.

Theoretically, I could follow the logic of the `tldextract` R package, which

- splits hosts wherever there is a `.` (example `aws.amazon.com` becomes a vector of `c('aws', 'amazon', 'com')`),
- then concatenates these components (except the first one) back together in an incremental way (for example, first concatenation would be `amazon.com`, second and last one would be `com`
- and for each concatenation checks whether there is a match in the TLD list.

Theoretically, I could translate this logic into Presto, but not easy without loops. So is there any existing solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with my own solution, heavily based on the R package `tldextract` which relies on the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/learn/). I explain the solution in detail [here](https://bernhard-clemm.medium.com/how-to-extract-domains-in-aws-athena-presto-sql-7f679dbcac72). This assumes you have imported the Public Suffix List into Presto as `domains_tld`, with a column called `tld` containing the TLDs.

First some toy data:

```
CREATE TABLE dat AS
SELECT url, url_extract_host(url) AS url_host FROM
(WITH temp AS (
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
('https://subsub.sub.example.co.uk/page?q=1234#abcd'),
('https://example.api.gov.uk/page?q=1234#abcd'),
('https://example.co.uk/page?q=1234#abcd'),
('https://www.example.com/page?q=1234#abcd'),
('https://example.com/page?q=1234#abcd')) AS tab (url))
SELECT url from temp)
```

Next, concatenate the resulting parts, starting from the last:

```
CREATE TABLE dat3 AS
SELECT url_host, part_1, part_2, part_3, part_4, part_5,
CASE
WHEN part_5 IS NOT NULL THEN part_5
WHEN part_5 IS NULL AND part_4 IS NOT NULL THEN part_4
WHEN part_4 IS NULL AND part_3 IS NOT NULL THEN part_3
WHEN part_3 IS NULL AND part_2 IS NOT NULL THEN part_2
END AS last,
CASE
WHEN part_5 IS NOT NULL THEN concat(part_4, '.', part_5)
WHEN part_5 IS NULL AND part_4 IS NOT NULL THEN concat(part_3, '.', part_4)
WHEN part_4 IS NULL AND part_3 IS NOT NULL THEN concat(part_2, '.', part_3)
END AS two_last,
CASE
WHEN part_5 IS NOT NULL THEN concat(part_3, '.', part_4, '.', part_5)
WHEN part_5 IS NULL AND part_4 IS NOT NULL THEN concat(part_2, '.', part_3, '.', part_4)
END AS three_last,
CASE
WHEN part_5 IS NOT NULL THEN concat(part_2, '.', part_3, '.', part_4, '.', part_5)
END AS four_last
FROM dat2
```

Next, bring this table into “long” format:

```
CREATE TABLE dat4 AS
SELECT * FROM
(WITH temp AS (
SELECT url_host, array[last, two_last, three_last, four_last] last_combs
FROM dat3)
SELECT url_host, pattern FROM temp
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(last_combs) as t(pattern))
WHERE pattern IS NOT NULL
```

Now, match the combinations to the list of TLDs:

```
CREATE TABLE dat5 AS
SELECT url_host, max_by(tld, tld_length) tld FROM
(SELECT url_host, pattern, d.tld, length(d.tld) tld_length
FROM dat4 h
LEFT JOIN domains_tld d ON h.pattern = d.tld
WHERE d.tld IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY url_host
```

Finally, we extract the domain out of the host!

```
SELECT url_host, tld, 
regexp_extract(url_host, concat(‘\p{Alnum}+\.’, tld)) AS sld 
FROM dat5
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked out the option with regular expression.
Does this not match to Your usecase or am I missunderstood something?
Give this a shot:

```sql
SELECT regexp_extract('aws.amazon.com', '(\w+\.\w+)$');
SELECT regexp_extract('sub.domain.aws.amazon.com', '(\w+\.\w+)$');
```

[image: Select regExp top level domain]

Comment: Unfortunately not. As mentioned in my question, to parse the host into domain is apparently not possible with regex. You can see with this example: `SELECT regexp_extract('bbc.co.uk', '(\w+\.\w+)$')`(here, the domain should be bbc.co.uk not co.uk)

Comment: Ah, right. Didnt had that edge case on my mind. Sorry.